# Firebase admin SDK not working on Cloud Scheduler (PubSub)

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have an app and I want to update weather details on every 5 minutes. I build a [PubSub function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/pubsub-events) on Google cloud function to get weather details from [weatherstack.com](https://weatherstack.com) website and then I'm trying to save the result on FireStore using [Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup).
The weather API working perfectly but the function that writes the data to FireStore not triggered.

My code:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const requestApi = require('request');

admin.initializeApp();

exports.WeatherPubSub = (event, context) => {

    requestApi({
        url: 'http://api.weatherstack.com/current?access_key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&query=XXXXX',
        method: "POST"
    }, (error, response, body) => {
        //console.log(JSON.parse(body));
        if (error) {
            console.log('error:', error); // Print the error if one occurred
        } else {
            console.log("=> "+ response.statusCode);
            //Call firestore to update weather data
            return admin.firestore().collection('settings').doc('weather').update({
                temperature: body.current['temperature'],
                humidity: body.current['humidity'],
                weather_descriptions: body.current['weather_descriptions'][0]
            }).then(function() {
                console.log('Done!');
            });
        }

    });

  //return null;
};
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "version": "0.0.2",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "firebase serve --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "8"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@google-cloud/pubsub": "^1.5.0",
    "firebase-admin": "^8.9.2",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.3.0",
    "request": "^2.88.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "firebase-functions-test": "^0.1.6"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must return a promise that resolves when all the asynchronous work in your Cloud Function is complete (i.e. call to the `weatherstack` API and Firestore [`update()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference#update) method).

This is explained in the official Firebase video series [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/video-series/). In particular watch the three videos titled "Learn JavaScript Promises" (Parts 2 & 3 especially focus on background triggered Cloud Functions, but it really worth watching Part 1 before).

---

The `request` library you are using supports callback interfaces natively **but does not return a promise**.

You can use the [`request-promise`](https://github.com/request/request-promise) library and the `rp()` method which "returns a regular Promises/A+ compliant promise" and then adapt your code as follows:

```
 //.....
 var options = {
        method: 'POST',
        uri: 'http://api.weatherstack.com/current?access_key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&query=XXXXX'
 };

return rp(options)
.then(body => {
       return admin.firestore().collection('settings').doc('weather').update({
                temperature: body.current['temperature'],
                humidity: body.current['humidity'],
                weather_descriptions: body.current['weather_descriptions'][0]
            }
})
.catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
    return null;  
});
 //.....
```

---

Also, you should double-check that the way you declare you cloud Function (`exports.WeatherPubSub = (event, context) => {...}`) is correct. It does not seem to be the case, see the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/pubsub-events) for more details.

Comment: @Mahmoud-Al-Nafei Hello, did you have time to look at the proposed solution?

Comment: Hello Renaud, I can confirm the issue was that the request library didn't return a promise. I use `request-promise` library and it works.
Thank you